# apt-get on solaris

Tags: unix, solaris, opensolaris

I am looking a file to download from the Internet.  On Debian it can be installed using `aptitude install librrd-dev` or `yum install librrd-dev` on Ubuntu. I am looking the same file for Solaris but I couldn't find the exact file. is there any comparable command on Solaris to download this dev file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you install Blastwave and use their repositories.  Traditionally, Solaris packages are distributed either as tarballs (which must be downloaded and un-tarred) or SystemV package files, .pkg.  To install a *.pkg file you would run "pkgadd .pkg".

If you want more online-repo style software installs, such as most (all?) Linux system support, configure blastwave.  http://www.blastwave.org/jir/blastwave.fam  Then you can do something along the lines of "pkgutil apache2" and it will download the pre-built/packaged file and install it.

Ah, yea, I kinda missed the part where you wanted a specific package.  Sunfreeware.com nor Blastwave seem to have it, but OpenCSW seems to.  Check out http://opencsw.oxdrove.co.uk/packages/unstable/i386/5.10/search/?cswq=rrd .  It has "rrdtool_dev: Development files for librrd.so.4"

Comment: Thanks very much!! exactly that I am looking for but unfortunately the machine I want to install it not connected to the internet and I am not sure how i can download it.

Comment: Search google for 
rrdtool_dev-1.4.5,REV=2011.03.21-SunOS5.9-i386-CSW.pkg.gz
it should bring up a list of mirrors.  Just just download like any other file, copy to portable media, insert media into Solaris box and you're off...

Comment: you are the man!!!! you made my day!!! thank you so very much. perfectly solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks :)  Happy to help.  If you have a spare minute, will you vote for my answer?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kendall's answer, note that a new package management system, IPS, was introduced with OpenSolaris and is now the standard with Solaris 11 Express and newer:

Here is its documentation:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/html/820-6572/index.html

It definitely supports automatic dependency management, multiple network repositories, CLI/GUI and other features Linux users are familiar with, plus some ZFS based specific ones that can prove very useful.

The previous SVR4 format is still supported so should you do not find a repository with the package you want available, you could still use pkg-get, pkgutil or similar.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this.  I have Solaris 10 U6 working As Expected, and refuse to change :-P  Thanks for educating me!